# Granting Cognitive Services Face API access to a sharepoint folder

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, powerapps, power-automate

I have a flow that stores a photo to sharepoint and then passes the url for this image to Face API preview connector in flow.

I currently get a "forbidden" error, which makes sense as the face api does not have access to the sharepoint location.

How do i grant the face api access to a sharepoint location to see all files in a folder?

Comment: I'm not enough proficient in Sharepoint to help you on that, that's more a general question for Sharepoint people, which would be "how can I properly expose a file externally". I guess you want to avoid it being totally public. For your information, the Face API connector you are using is limited to passing an url, but the real API being can be called with the file directly, which would be interesting in your case

Comment: yea, i considered the "full" api but wanted to try the flow connector.
I dont think its a sharepoint question, i think its more of an azure security question,i.e. what mechanism does azure have to allow assignment of an account or SPN to a service such as cognitive services, which can then be granted access within sharepoint as per normal processes.

Comment: there is no built-in mechanism specific for Azure Cognitive Services for that, like it could exist in Azure for example for IP restrictions for SQL databases. Even for Azure Cognitive Search, there seems to be no indexer for Sharepoint documents (see https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/37448950-indexer-crawler-on-sharepoint-document-library-or)

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no built-in mechanism for Azure Cognitive  connector to access SharePoint, you could check this feedback Nicolas R shared [no indexer for Sharepoint documents](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/37448950-indexer-crawler-on-sharepoint-document-library-or).

So you could use SharePoint connector to get the file directly and pass the file content to the face API connector.